# CSS aligniment problem

Tags: css, alignment

I am designing home page of my domain registration website and I am stuck at one place. Please go through the website at http://a2host.in/

In Firefox and Google Chrome the Search and Go Button are in same alignment with the text and select box but in Opera and IE8, they are falling down a bit.

I have tried out all the things but I am not able to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: Garbage in, Garbage out. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fa2host.in%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please comment out the following CSS3 properties (please see below) in the .regbutton class of your [stylesheet](http://a2host.in/ui/resellerdata/270000_299999/286393/supersite/themes/ClassicBlue-Aviash/css/common/common.css) and then try

```
.regbutton, .regbutton:visited {
    background: #222 url(/getImage.php?src=myUploadedImages/overlay.png) repeat-x;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px 6px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*-moz-border-radius: 6px;*/ /*comment out all CSS3 properties*/
    /*-webkit-border-radius: 6px;*/
    /*-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);*/
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);*/
    /*text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);*/
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);*/
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of unneccesary styling. In essence, this is what you want:
[Basic form without floats](http://www.jsfiddle.net/dSyTg/)

You can tweak the font-sizes and colors here, until you have what you want. But this is a good starting point, because it is cross browser identical.

Also, think about using the `<button>` element instead of the `<input type="button">`. It gives you more freedom in styling.

Form-controls are a pain to get them look good in all browsers, especially buttons and select-boxes.

Answer (score 0):

try to set `border:none` for your buttons